# button with href does not work inside collapsed

Tags: html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a collapsed model which show more information about client, and insid it, I have a button, when I click, I don't get the view markerd in href.
How can I make this button working please!

```
  <a class="item  item-icon-left " >
            <i class="icon ion-android-arrow-dropdown-circle" ng-model="collapsed" ng-click="collapsed=!collapsed"></i>
            {{x.Marque}}   
          </a>
          <a ng-show="collapsed">
                <table>
                      <thead >
                         <td>   
                             <label> Code:  </label> {{x.CodeClient}}    <br/> 
                             <label> Nom:   </label> {{x.NomClient}}     <br/> 
                            <button class="button" href="#/modifClient">Modifier</a>
                         </td> 
    ...
```

Comment: `button` does not have the `href` attribute. use an anchor tag `a`

Comment: I tried this: <a class="button button-info" href="#/modifClient" > Enregistrer </a> and still not working

Comment: if you're trying to go to a different page, get rid of the `#`, so it should be like this: `href="/modifClient"`

Comment: I change it, but does not work

Answer (score 0):

Use an anchor `<a>` tag or if you want to keep button add a click event and do navigation inside your click handler. I will suggest to change it to `<a>` tag to keep right semantic.

Comment: I tried this: <a class="button button-info" href="#/modifClient" >
                      Enregistrer
                     </a> and still not working